# System display time is out of sync with specified install time on Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS install

Tags: apt, updates, time, intel-cpu

On installing Ununtu 22.04.02 LTS from a USB key on to an HP Pavilion Laptop. I have encountered the following problem:

When I run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`

I get:

```
E: Release file for http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 12h 51min 3s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 12h 51min 44s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 13h 36min 36s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

I further found that the time displayed in Ubuntu is not the correct time. I reinstalled the distro to make sure the right time zone had been selected which was the case but the problems persist. Before the Ubuntu install, Mint had been installed and there were no such problems.

So I ran: `journalctl -p 4 -b | head -n 5` and got the following:

```
Sep 27 05:43:55 eml kernel: x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
Sep 27 05:43:55 eml kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Sep 27 05:43:55 eml kernel: MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
Sep 27 05:43:55 eml kernel: MMIO Stale Data CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/processor_mmio_stale_data.html for more details.
Sep 27 05:43:55 eml kernel:  #3
```

Read through:

```
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html#mds-sys-info
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/processor_mmio_stale_data.html
```

But don't fully understand it.

From this however I did run

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/mds

Mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
```

and

```
timedatectl

               Local time: Fri 2023-09-29 11:11:29 NZDT
           Universal time: Thu 2023-09-28 22:11:29 UTC
                 RTC time: Thu 2023-09-28 22:11:29
                Time zone: Pacific/Auckland (NZDT, +1300)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

The last command is the same as on another machine with Ubuntu that does not exhibit the above problems. However NZDT, UTC and RTC time differ markedly when compared. So I am out of my depth here and would much appreciate some help on this.
The cpu is: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz`.

Comment: I am afraid that the suggestions don't work because UTC time is wrong. All times are incorrect.

Comment: My hunch is to do ```timedatectl set-local-rtc 0```. But since UTC is incorrect this makes no sence.

Comment: I just checked the BIOS settings in the laptop and noticed that Time and Date are incorrect. So I think the problem starts here. But should the Bios time and date be set to UTC or local time? And after that will a simple reboot solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set the BIOS time and date to UTC in the BIOS settings, save the changes in the BIOS settings, exit from the BIOS, and continue to boot normally.

Your HP Pavilion laptop has an Intel Core i5 processor. The kernel and corresponding *intel-microcode* package (`sudo apt install intel-microcode`) updates fully address the MDS flaws if your processor does not support Hyper-Threads, also known as Symmetric Multi-Threading (SMT).

Comment: That did not work. However what did work is setting Bios time to UTC. All times are correct. Now I can run ```sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y```. After running I rebooted the system and ran ```journalctl -p 4 -b | head -n 5```. I still however get the same "CPU bug/data leak possible" output as above. How should this be addressed? Reinstall after changing Bios clock to UTC?

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu with correct time in Bios. Timedatectl shows correct times. However I still get "CPU bug/data leak possible" as above.